# Perl regex to match different types of space characters but not tabulation

Tags: regex, perl, unicode

When working with `.tsv` files containing text, I sometimes need to normalize different types of whitespace characters (non-breaking space, em-space etc.).
Is there a way to match all of them, but not the field separator (tab), so it would be possible to process the whole file at once, without splitting it into columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character classes `\s` and `\h` match all space and horizontal space, respectively. You can use a negated character class to exclude certain characters, for example `[^\S\t]` or `[^\H\t]` – all (horizontal) space characters except the tabulator.

That is probably the simplest solution, but you can also use various Unicode properties. For example `[^\H\p{POSIX_Cntrl}]` would be all horizontal space characters that are not control characters (the tab is a control character), and equivalently `\p{Zs}` contains all Unicode space separators (which also excludes the tab). However, none of these Unicode properties make explicit that you merely want to exclude the tabulator.

Answer (score -1):

`\s` matches any whitespace character including tab (`\t`) -> (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)

Use `[\r\n\f\v ]` which will match all whitespace characters except tab (`\t`).

Or use `[\r\f\v ]` which will match all whitespace except tab (`\t`) and newline (`\n`).

Comment: Your answer is correct for ASCII, but does not consider Unicode characters like non-breaking spaces or em-spaces that are mentioned in the question. The `\s` charclass will also match Unicode space characters, not just the ASCII space characters you mentioned.